# Merging Mercurial branches from separate repositories

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging

I'm trying to figure out how to merge branches from a separate repo into the current.

I have the following:

PJT1
- contains branches default and foodog

PJT2
- contains branch default

from PJT2, I do the following:

```
$ hg fetch -y ../PJT1 -r foodog -m "this is a test"
```

Now, if I look in PJT2, I see the correct files and changes.  However, I if I do `hg branches`, I get the following:

```
[someone@myhome pjt2]$ hg branches
foodog                         1:c1e14fde816b
default                        0:7b1adb938f71 (inactive)
```

and `hg branch` reveals the following:

```
[someone@myhome pjt2]$ hg branch
foodog
```

How do I get the contents from PJT1's `foodog` branch into PJT2's `default` branch?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to merge, but keep in mind changes on branch foodog will always be on foodog -- branches never go away but they can be hidden.  This sequence of commands is as close as you'll get to what you're asking:

```
cd PJT2
hg update default # just in case you were somewhere else
hg pull ../PJT1 -r foodog  # that gets you foodog
hg merge foodog  # that merges the changes into default
hg commit # commit the merge
hg update foodog # go to the most recent change in foodog (note: it is not a 'head')
hg commit --close-branch
```

After the merge `hg branches` will still show `foodog` unless you do `hg branches --active` which only shows branches that have heads on them.  After the `commit --close-branch` you won't see `foodog` unless you do `hg branches --closed`.

It's because branches in Mercurial never go away entirely (a design feature) that they're often reserved only for life-long things like `release-1.0` or `stable`.  For short-lived efforts like bugs and features consider using bookmarks instead.  Here's a great comparison of the two: http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using the [rebase](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) extension. It would look something like this:

```
hg fetch -y ../PJT1 -r foodog -m "this is a test"
hg rebase --source <sRev> --dest <dRev>
```

The rebase action will detatch changeset *sRev* and all descendents and apply the group of changes to changeset *dRev*. By default, the changes will be applied on the default branch. So, in your case, *sRev* would be the first changeset on branch *foodog* and *dRev* would be the *default* changeset you want to apply them to.

Finally, If you want to override this and preserve the source branch name you can use rebase option `--keepbranches`. Your questions indicates that this is exactly what you do not want to do, but it should still be noted.